# Create and Update wiki pages using MediaWiki::API

Tags: perl, mediawiki-api

I am newbie in perl programming. I'm creating wikipages using perl.
So, I am updating whole wiki page using MediaWiki ::API interface.
Code is as follows:

```
my $wiki = MediaWiki::API->new();

# [...code...]

$wiki->edit( { title => "My_page", text => $all_lines, action => 'edit'} );
```

My question is, What if I have to update only some portion of webpage ?? 
NOT ENTIRE WEBPAGE ?
And selection of that part of webpage is dynamic. That means, it depends on what input file I get from user.

So lets say, if user says modify "Introduction" section in webpage then,I should be able to search that particular section and update ?

Any pointers or any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [`section` parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aEdit#Parameters).